# Is it possible for Wireshark to drop packets purposely?

Tags: networking, voip, wireshark

I would like to test something like VoIP. I would like to test with some "artificial packet loss". Is Wireshark able to do this? Or is there any good solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use tools like [WANEM](http://wanem.sourceforge.net/) to simulate packet loss. It's a Live-CD, so you can put it on a system between your server & clients.

Answer (score 2):

WANEM as mentioned is a good tool. If you're doing on Linux you can also play with the buffer queues etc, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614795/simulate-delayed-and-dropped-packets-on-linux) page which has many answer to this questions already including netem and queue examples;

Also, you can use tools like iperf/jperf to saturate a link.

You can also use iptables to drop packets, like [this](http://code.nomad-labs.com/2010/03/11/simulating-dropped-packets-aka-crappy-internets-with-iptables/).